# Does Pgbouncer answer to kill command?

Tags: postgresql, azure, shell, kubernetes, pgbouncer

I have configured Pgbouncer as a sidecar pattern in one of my pods in Azure Kubernetes based on [Azure Oss Db Tools Pgbouncer Sidecar](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azure-oss-db-tools-pgbouncer-sidecar) documentation. It has the following container lifecycle hook:

```sh
lifecycle:
  preStop:
    exec:
      command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "killall -INT pgbouncer && sleep 120"]
```

I believe the intended purpose of this command is to wait 120 seconds until any running query finishes.

---

To understand what it does, I opened two interactive shells inside the Pgbouncer container. In the first shell, I executed the `killall` command and in the second shell, I executed `ps` command multiple times.

#### First shell:

```sh
/ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 postgres  0:00 /usr/bin/pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
    6 postgres  0:00 /bin/sh
   30 postgres  0:00 ps
/ $
/ $
/ $ killall -INT pgbouncer && sleep 120
```

#### Second shell:

```sh
/ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 postgres  0:00 /usr/bin/pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
    6 postgres  0:00 /bin/sh
   33 postgres  0:00 /bin/sh
   40 postgres  0:00 sleep 120
   41 postgres  0:00 ps
/ $
/ $
/ $ ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 postgres  0:00 /usr/bin/pgbouncer /etc/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
    6 postgres  0:00 /bin/sh
   33 postgres  0:00 /bin/sh
   42 postgres  0:00 ps
```

After 120 seconds, Pgbouncer main process is still running (See the output from the second shell). I thought this should have terminated both my terminal sessions since it was supposed to kill Pgbouncer process (`PID` = `1`) and stop the container.

---

If I try to kill using the below command:

```sh
/ $ kill 1
/ $ command terminated with exit code 137
```

I see that both my terminal sessions are immediately terminated and the container is stopped.

---

I want to understand whether we really need this lifecycle hook since it is not properly working? Or did I make any mistake trying to understand what it does?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference here. The `killall -INT` sends INT signal while `kill` sends TERM signal if no signal is specified. You can try again with `kill -INT 1` to see whether it gets the same behavior. I think the `pgbouncer` process is also catching INT.

Here is reference to the [site](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/blob/cfbb8a3ae7a09968e9cd12f4afb907496d72d679/src/main.c):

```c
int cf_shutdown; /* 1 - wait for queries to finish, 2 - shutdown immediately */

...

static void handle_sigterm(evutil_socket_t sock, short flags, void *arg)
{
    log_info("got SIGTERM, fast exit");
    /* pidfile cleanup happens via atexit() */
    exit(1);
}
    
static void handle_sigint(evutil_socket_t sock, short flags, void *arg)
{
    log_info("got SIGINT, shutting down");
    sd_notify(0, "STOPPING=1");
    if (cf_reboot)
        die("takeover was in progress, going down immediately");
    if (cf_pause_mode == P_SUSPEND)
        die("suspend was in progress, going down immediately");
    cf_pause_mode = P_PAUSE;
    cf_shutdown = 1;
}
```

Pgbouncer stops processing any more queries when the INT signal is given while the TERM signal will terminate the process immediately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The reason I used `kill 1` is to show what should happen if Pgbouncer process is actually killed. The question I need answering is why `killall -INT pgbouncer && sleep 120` is not working as we wanted it to be.

Comment: It's not working since INT does not terminate the process, so to terminate/exit you need `killall -TERM pgbouncer && sleep 120`. The `pgbouncer ` handles INT and TERM in separate functions

Comment: Wow, thank you for the explanation and the reference . So, `SIGINT` is only for interrupting pgbouncer like pausing it from doing any more tasks?

Comment: I have no exp on detail of pgbouncer. From what I understand it's setting some vars to do something later. Your guess seems right

Comment: I just checked it. It stops processing any more queries after giving the INT signal. I'll update your answer with what INT signal does. Thanks again for the help. Cheers 